# .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, .net-4.0

A colleague of mine just told me it is not a good idea installing .NET Framework 4.0 on a Windows server 2003. He said the servers behave strange. Is there something on it or he just playing me for a fool ?

I'm have some software that needs .NET Framework 4.0.

EDIT

He said actually it slows down the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft supports installing any combination of .NET framework versions side by side as long as they are compatible with the operating system on which you install them (.NET 4.0 can be installed on server 2003 as long as you have service pack 2).  As applications typically use only the one they are built for, I wouldn't expect anything bad to happen as a result of installing an additional version.

Some applications (specifically IIS) allow you to select which version to use in a particular context.  You can't typically change this setting without causing problems, as the behaviour of each version is different.  However, his comment is absurdly overbroad.

Answer (score 2):

He likely has as little knowledge about maintaining servers as you do. .NET 4.0 should not cause issues - .NET frameworks are side by side installs - especially not for the SERVER.

Maybe he installed other software. Or just has no idea what "strange" means - I definitely do not know what he could mean. And it is not a term someone with a clue would use.

Comment: He said actually it slow down the system.

Comment: Yeah. Right. As i said - little knowledge.

Comment: From this tiny glimpse, the guy really looks like one of those types of IT staff that treat everything as mystic voodoo and have absolutely no knowledge of what they are doing beyond following exact instructions.  Those are the guys you want to sack, not to have mentoring others ;)

Comment: Yes. As sad as it is - those are around, especially in larger organizations. Been fighting them repeatedly in projects, partially o a funny degree (develop highly parallel software targetting a 12x2 core  server with 64gb ram on a dual core xp machine - and profile it there).

Comment: I just decided to change gears and become a pentester (so I can pull their pants down at every possible opportunity).